# Can Not POST NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express, post, axios

I was trying to make an axios post request to an express server and I receive that `Error: Request failed with status code 404 at createError`. Postman says Can Not POST. I don't know what could be wrong, i'm new in all this, so all the help it's good, thanks.
Axios and Express server are from 2 different link. They are google cloud function.
Thanks for the help

Axios Post Request :

```
exports.notification = (req, res) => {

var axios = require('axios');
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = {
 headers: {
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Content-Type' : 'text/html',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json' } 
};

var info = {
 ids:[req.body.id,req.body.id1],
 type: req.body.type,
 event: req.body.action,
 subscription_id: req.body.subid,
 secret_field_1:null,
 secret_field_2:null,
 updated_attributes:{
   field_name:[req.body.oname,req.body.nname]}
};  

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(info);

return axios.post('https://us-central1-copper-mock.cloudfunctions.net/api/notification-example', myJSON)
 .then((result) => {
   console.log("DONE",result);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log("ERROR",err);
   console.log("Error response:");
   console.log(err.response.data);   
   console.log(err.response.status);  
   console.log(err.response.headers);
 })
};
```

Express Server

```
const express = require ('express');
const https = require ('https');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');

const app = express();

const port  = 8080;

// ROUTES
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of router
router.use(function(req, res, next) { // route middleware that will happen on every request
 console.log(req.method, req.url); // log each request to the console
 next(); // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/',require ('./Routers/API/home'));

app.use('/leads',require ('./Routers/API/leads'));

app.use('/people',require ('./Routers/API/people'));

app.use('/companies',require ('./Routers/API/companies'));

app.use('/opportunities',require ('./Routers/API/opportunities'));

app.use('/projects',require ('./Routers/API/projects'));

app.use('/tasks',require ('./Routers/API/tasks'));

app.use('/activities',require ('./Routers/API/activities'));

app.use('/notification-example',require ('./Routers/API/notification_example'));

app.use('/', router); // apply the routes to our application

// START THE SERVER
// ==============================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening ' + port);

module.exports={
  app
};
```

Notification Route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//const notification_example = require('../../Notification');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('DATA',JSON.parse(res.data));
    console.log('BODY',JSON.parse(res.body));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: At first look, it appears the url is `/api/notification-example`, but the route is defined for `/notification-example`.

Comment: Thanks, now I have another problem. Axios didn't read "data" that I post (info) and send the TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at axios.post.then.catch. Can you help me?